# Remove preview (and thumbnail) from MP4 file

Tags: video, thumbnails, mp4, previews

How does one remove the preview and thumbnail from a MP4 file (or other video format)? I just simply want to remove it and have a blank icon and preview image. I'm using OpenShot video editor which automatically creates a preview and I haven't been able to find a way to edit or remove the preview image. - Thanks, s_schroe